# Fedora 34 Lenovo ThinkPad Docking Station USB not working

Tags: fedora

Upon installing Fedora 34 on a ThinkPad, the Fedora ThinkPad Dockingstation, connected via Thunderbolt, works only partially. The display ports work fine, but the USB ports don't work.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what the underlying problem is but here is the solution:

The boltctl tool controls the thunderbolt device manager. The problem is resolved by forgetting and then re-authenticating and re-enrolling the Docking Station.

1. List all thunderbolt devices

> boltctl list

2. Identify the devices uuid
3. If already connected, forget the device

> boltctl forget [uuid]

4. Re-authenticate device

> boltctl authorize [uuid]

5. Re-enroll device

> boltctl enroll [uuid]

... and voilà, it should work now.

Comment: Adding to this, this seems to undo itself on reboot. I just made a shell script executing this and put it into /etc/rc.d/init.d so it gets executed on boot.

Comment: once I issued `boltctl forget [uuid]` I can't see the device anymore, any hint on how to restore it?